# HTML to PDF script

Tags: bash, unix, pdf, curl

I would like some help...

I'm currently downloading pages with wget using curl session cookie like this:

```
wget --header="Host: www.######.###" --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/63.0.3239.84 Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36" --header="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" --header="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,##-##;q=0.8,##;q=0.7,nl;q=0.6" --header="Cookie: s=kfegregregregqv3; _ga=GA1.2.52341686.1516234087; _gid=GA1.2.2234276049.154324915" --header="Connection: keep-alive" "http://www.########.##/#####/#####/" -O "####.html" -c
```

It works awesome, being that this website requires a login to acess the page...

The problem is that the page.html is saved without any images...

Is there anyway to,in bash script, convert this webpage to PDF using the cookie validation keep alive?

Thanks!

Comment: The `page.html` is saved "without any images" because it is `html` code. This is how the web works. If you want the images, you need download them also.

Comment: I do know how html pages work... though can you help in how do i get the images?

Comment: for (belated) reference, likely all that was missing for making `wget` also download images is using anything that functions similarly to `wget --page-requisites  --convert-links ...`, which could also be accomplished by mirroring, eg., `wget --mirror --convert-links ...` (see mirroring, https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Very-Advanced-Usage ). However, converting to PDF is another issue entirely (hence, a comment, not an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in python if finding solution with wget is taking time.

Install wkhtmltopdf. If you are on Mac: `brew install Caskroom/cask/wkhtmltopdf`. If you are on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`.

Then install pdfkit: `pip install pdfkit`

```
import pdfkit
options = {
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'custom-header' : [
        ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
    ]
    'cookie': [
        ('cookie-name1', 'cookie-value1'),
        ('cookie-name2', 'cookie-value2'),
    ],
    'no-outline': None
}
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf', options=options)
```

Copy the above code and save it as yourfilename.py. Replace the cookie and options value as per your requirement.

Run python yourfilename.py from terminal